# cmake error when installing uhd v3.14.0.0 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnuradio, usrp, uhd

It's my first time to install uhd from source, and I basically follow this page
[USRP Hardware Driver and USRP Manual](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_install.html)
My Python version is **3.8.10**
However when I get to this point:
`~/workarea/uhd/host/build$ cmake ..`, I get the error like the following:

```
-- Python checking for Python version 2.7 or greater - "assert platform.python_version() >= '2.7' and platform.python_version() < '3.0'" failed
```

```
-- Configuring LibUHD support...
--   Dependency Boost_FOUND = TRUE
--   Dependency HAVE_PYTHON_PLAT_MIN_VERSION = FALSE
--   Dependency HAVE_PYTHON_MODULE_MAKO = TRUE
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/UHDComponent.camke:59 (message):
  Dependencies for required component LibUHD not met.
```

I think the only problem is the wrong `platform.python_version()`. But it seems like I'm the only one with this condition and can't find any way to solve it.

Has anyone ever been in that situation? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't solve this problem, but I find another way to install uhd and gnuradio. It seems easier to install them by PPA.

I don't know how to choose the version of uhd, because I installed uhd v3.15.0.0 automatically. But the version of gnuradio is optional, so I installed v3.8.1.0. They seems to be working normally.

So, I leave the question here. Maybe someone or myself will answer that question later.